is there a Package in R to generate ocean routes?
I apologize for the very general question, but I don't know how to proceed.
Some of you know an R package to automatically generate routes in the sea, considering a series of variables that I give it as input (e.g. marine protected areas, Posidonia beds, bathymetry, slope, military area, restricted zone). Thanks in advance to anyone who can give me an idea on which path to take.
